# Linq Select compiling differently between C# and VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have the following C# code which compiles correctly:

```
private string formatterCSharp(int number)
{
    return "n" + number;
}

private void testInCSharp()
{
    IEnumerable<int> list = new List<int>();

    IEnumerable<string> formatted = list.Select(formatterCSharp);
}
```

As you can see, `formatted` should contain the contents of `list`, with `formatterCSharp` applied to each.

When I try to replicate this code in VB, I come up with this:

```
Private Function formatterVisualBasic(ByVal number As Integer) As String
    Return "n" + number
End Function

Private Sub testInVB()
    Dim list As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)

    Dim formatted As IEnumerable(Of String) = list.Select(formatterVisualBasic)
End Sub
```

However I get two compilation errors on the `Select` statement in VB.

```
BC30455
    Argument not specified for parameter 'number' of 'Private Function formatterVisualBasic(number As Integer) As String'.

BC30518
    Overload resolution failed because no accessible '[Select]' can be called with these arguments:
        Extension method 'Public Function [Select](Of TResult)(selector As Func(Of Integer, TResult)) As IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'Enumerable': Type parameter 'TResult' cannot be inferred.
        Extension method 'Public Function [Select](Of TResult)(selector As Func(Of Integer, Integer, TResult)) As IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'Enumerable': Type parameter 'TResult' cannot be inferred.
```

Comment: Here is the correct fix : Dim formatted As IEnumerable(Of String) = list.Select(Function(x) formatterVisualBasic(x))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Dim formatted As IEnumerable(Of String) = list.Select(AddressOf formatterVisualBasic)
```

In VB.net you can't specify function name to pass it like that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Okay first off the select query is formed differently in VB.NET, here's how it should look:

```
    Dim formatted As IEnumerable(Of String) = list.Select(Function(x As String) x = formatterVisualBasic(mynumber))
```

Secondly, if you want to get the same exception as in your C# code, you must add parentheses to the function call **formatterVisualBasic**, so that it is recognized as a function

```
    Dim formatted As IEnumerable(Of String) = list.Select(Function(x As String) x = formatterVisualBasic())
```

Comment: This is not the syntax I am looking for. I do not want to do `Select(Function(x) someFunction(X)`, I only want to do `Select(someFunction)`. Andrey's answer above is correct.